Backup files only that are newer than a specific date?
I have made a backup B1 on my external hard drive on date D. This hard drive is now in a different location (not at my house).
Now I want to make a backup B2 on another external drive, but only of those files that where changed after the date D.
As soon as I have B1 back in my hands, I will update B1 and delete B2. The point of B2 is to have security regarding the changes since date D, until I can update my backup properly again.
How can I do this even if I do not have B1 at hand?

That will depend on how you backed things up. Not knowing how/what you did, it's easy to find & copy files newer than the last time you backed things up using find .... Let's say you backed up stuff on the 1st of October: find -type f -mtime -71 .. you can feed that list to tar.

@tink: I did the backup by basically just copying all the files to the external harddrive. Nothing fancy. Yes, I think this is what I need: A find with saying "everything that has been changed after the date" and then saying for every file to copy it to another place. The idea with tar is to put everything into an archive directly, right? What is important for me is that the file structure is copied as well; in other words, that the parent directories are copied. How would the full command look like?
